# Database Data Types

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

What database data type do I need to use to store a numerical value with 18 digits after the decimal place? I've tried double and float but it doesn't work it only shows 16 digits after the decimal place. I'm using MS SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your values are not too big, you want to use `DECIMAL`.  Something like `DECIMAL(20, 18)` (adjust the first value for the total number of digits in the number).

You can read about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: What if the total number of digits vary?

Comment: @user1302054 . . . Just use a large enough value for the first digit . . . `DECIMAL(30, 18)` should be big and precise enough for most measurements.